# How can I automatically add an additional apostrophe when entered by a user so as to not break their query?

Tags: sql, r

I have a function where users specify start date (`sd`), end date (`ed`) and `site` in order to produce a graph.

I have built a query that inputs the values entered accordingly; however, whenever `site` contains an apostrophe, it naturally breaks the query.

In order to allow apostrophes within SQL queries, you must add it twice (i.e. `Dave's Site` becomes `Dave''s Site`).

How can I allow for this to automatically add another apostrophe when one is entered by a user?

Relevant code snippet:

```
query <- paste0("SELECT *
FROM CV.SAM.EventBASE
WHERE site = '", site, "'
AND start_date >= '", sd, "'
AND end_date <= '", ed, "'")
```

Function call:

```
plot_range("2021-02-01", "2021-02-28", "Dave's Site")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a replacement here on all character variables which you intend to bind as string literals in your SQL query:

```r
site <- "Dave's Site"
site <- gsub("'", "''", site, fixed=TRUE)
site

[1] "Dave''s Site"
```

However, the typical way to handle this problem when interfacing with SQL is to use a prepared statement, which handles this type of escaping problem automatically.  If R supports something like this, you should use that instead.

Comment: This works for the query, although the issue now now that when `site` is printed on the graph, it shows up as `Dave''s Site`; how can I restore the single apostrophe here?

Comment: I have worked it out: I simply reverse the addition after the query has been built: `site <- gsub("''", "'", site, fixed = TRUE)`.

Comment: @Mus See if you can find an R library which lets you used prepared statement, maybe ODBC.  That way, you don't have to massage your data this way.

Comment: I'm using `RODBC` currently.

Comment: Would you please elaborate more on prepared statements and how I might go about using them?

Comment: @Mus I believe that [this blog](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.r-bloggers.com/2014/08/parameterized-sql-queries/amp/) would be a good place to start.